# Python help needed for nested for loops and tsv data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below python code which reads data from a tsv file and tries to invoke another method to get distance between two points

***Code:***

```
import csv

def myMethod:

with open('data.tsv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for source in reader:
        for dest in reader:
            if source[0]!=dest[0]:
                print("The source id is: " +source[0])
                print("The source long is: " +source[1])
                print("The source lati is: " +source[2])
                print("The dest id is: " +dest[0])
                print("The dest long is: " +dest[1])
                print("The dest lati is: " +dest[2])
                result=calculateDistance(source[1],source[2],dest[1],dest[2])
                print "The distance between tower" +source[0]+ "and tower " +dest[0]+ "is" +result
```

My tsv file data looks like this:

```
id    Longitude    Latitude

1   -4.143452   5.342044
2   -3.913602   5.341612
3   -3.967045   5.263331
4   -4.070007   5.451365
5   -3.496235   6.729410
```

when is see the result, the outer for loop runs only one time. I want to calculate the distance for every combination in the tsv file. I am wondering what i might be doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the problem and update the code as shown below:

```
import csv

def myMethod:

with open('data.tsv','r') as f:
    reader1 = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t'))
f.close()

with open('data.tsv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for source in reader:
        for dest in reader1:
            if source[0]!=dest[0]:
                print("The source id is: " +source[0])
                print("The source long is: " +source[1])
                print("The source lati is: " +source[2])
                print("The dest id is: " +dest[0])
                print("The dest long is: " +dest[1])
                print("The dest lati is: " +dest[2])
result=calculateDistance(source[1],source[2],dest[1],dest[2])
                print "The distance between tower" +source[0]+ "and tower " +dest[0]+ "is" +result
```